# Creating procedures to let them do the work of foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, partitioning

i have  three table which are linked through foreign keys in MySQL database version 5.5.

I am thinking to partition these three tables as their size is around 50 GB.

I am thinking to partition these tables but partitioning in MySQl doesn't support foreign keys

Can we create a procedure to check the foreign key dependency during insert,update and delete ?

Answer (score 0):

Not procedure but you can definitely check this using Triggers.